# Deploying to Google App Engine Tutorial Enhancer Exception

Tags: google-app-engine, exception, gwt

I've just started to learn GWT and Google App Engine.  For better or worse, I started with doing the Deploying to Google App Engine tutorial as found here:

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/appengine.html

This tutorial builds on an RPC tutorial as found here:

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html

I downloaded the StockWatcher project and did the RPC tutorial without a problem and then went back to continue with the "Deploying to Google App Engine" tutorial.

I'm using Eclipse, but I'm guessing that the person who did the RPC tutorial didn't because I had to follow the instruction section to "Set up a project (without Eclipse)"

All was going well until I got to the last step of the tutorial to test the app.  When I get the the line:

List stocks = (List) q.execute(getUser());

in the file, src/com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.server/StockServiceImpl.java.  The full code is in the tutorial, so I won't upload that here.

The q.execute() statement throws the following exception:

javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: No meta data for com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.server.Stock.  Perhaps you need to run the enhancer on this class?
NestedThrowables:
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.FatalNucleusUserException: No meta data for com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.server.Stock.  Perhaps you need to run the enhancer on this class?

I tried for a few days now without making any progress.  I don't understand how I run the "enhancer" nor do I know what that means.  Is this the name of a tool and they simply forgot to capitalize the proper noun to Enhancer?

I suspect because I didn't create the project from scratch, there's some setting the tutorial failed to mention you need to have when downloading the RPC project as your starting point.

While I don't know what the suggestion about the "enhancer" means, I did see this section in build.xml if that helps....

```
   name="datanucleusenhancer"
   classpathref="tools.class.path"
   classname="org.datanucleus.enhancer.tools.EnhancerTask" />
<datanucleusenhancer
   classpathref="tools.class.path"
   failonerror="true">
  <fileset dir="war/WEB-INF/classes" includes="**/*.class" />
</datanucleusenhancer>
```

Can anyone give me a hint as to what I did wrong?  Thanks.

no snark please

Answer (score 0):

After carefully going through the tutorial again, I missed the following line in Stock.java:

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)

This seems to make the problem go away, but I don't see how the message was helpful.

avax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: No meta data for com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.server.Stock. Perhaps you need to run the enhancer on this class? NestedThrowables: org.datanucleus.store.appengine.FatalNucleusUserException: No meta data for com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.server.Stock. Perhaps you need to run the enhancer on this class?

First, it suggests to "run the enhancer", which isn't what you want to do, nor could I figure out how to run the enhancer so I could confirm that doing so wouldn't help.  I also don't see where there's a description in the tutorial on how this line creates meta data.  This is not described in the section about the code on "Things to notice."

Comment: I'll leave this for someone to confirm this is "an answer".

Comment: I am getting same error...Even I have written @PersistenceCapable...
Still error is there...
what else can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the class annotation mentioned in the previous answer, also make sure you have getters and setters for your fields.   In particular, I had problems without the function getId().

```
  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
  }
```